# Знаки препинания при приложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, приложение, причастный-оборот, запятая-и-тире

«...повествует нам о двух русских офицерах, — Жилине и Костылине — служивших во время Кавказской войны».

Скажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли здесь расставлены знаки препинания (конкретно интересует запятая)?

Comment: За отметку о запятых речь, а по жизни — без точек, и прописных?

Comment: что, простите? первый раз встречаетесь с лэпслоком?

Comment: Приветствую вас на сайте ***русского языка***! *Лапслок* — вещь, наверно, удобная, но не здесь. Интересен, право же, ваш вопрос. Я его ещё раз подправила. И оценила — будем считать, авансом.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Саша, глазастый ты наш (каюсь, пропустила же ж кавказ**с**кую тему), с Новым годом!

Comment: спасибо, конечно, однако данный стиль отличается не только удобством, к Вашему сведению. я прекрасно знаю, на какой платформе задаю вопрос, в какой форме – тоже. не стану писать об изменениях / появлениях / новомодных введениях в русском языке, лишь проконстатирую факт того, что Вас не затруднило прочтение моего поста, к тому же написание комментария под ним(что также и обеспечилось пунктуационным оформлением), так что...

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова С Новым, Римма! И всем того же!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Правильно:  «...повествует нам о двух русских офицерах **– Жилине и Костылине,  служивших во время Кавказской войны».**

**Пояснение**

Это тема [§ 19. Обособленные приложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111)

**Пункт 6.** Собственное имя лица или кличка животного выступает в роли обособленного приложения, если **поясняет** либо уточняет нарицательное существительное (перед таким приложением можно без изменения смысла вставить слова а именно, то есть).

**Пункт 10.** При обособлении приложений вместо запятой употребляется **тире**: <...>
3) для выделения (с двух сторон) приложения, носящего характер пояснения.

**Примечание**. Одно тире (первое или второе) опускается: 1) если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения ставится **запятая.**

В приведенном предложении **запятой** обособлен причастный оборот.

Comment: Александр, к пункту 10, может,  подпункт (2) больше походит (про конец фразы)?

Comment: Sharon, вы, наверно, видели, мой комиентарий, который я удалил? Без добавки предложение "При обособлении приложений вместо запятой употребляется **тире**" не является правдой :)). Я, конечно, просмотрел ещё раз все три подпункта и думаю, что всё-таки 3-й больше подходит. Во-первых, он о двух тире, а во-вторых, он согласуется с 6-м пунктом, который вы приводите: "**поясняет** либо уточняет нарицательное существительное".

Comment: Но если не согласны, то всё равно нужно что-то добавить.

Comment: Спасибо,я так оставлю, как вы исправили.

Comment: У вас уже четыре плюса... Поставлю пятый, потому что я думаю так же, — это действительно наивернейший ответ.